# Wrapper Monitoring Library Facade For Node JS

Tags: node.js, monitoring

We have to integrate with Datadog library (datadogstatsd) and to avoid tight coupling I was looking for a wrapper library in node js.

I have used [Micrometer](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer) before which allowed us to easily switch from prometheus to Datadog for one of our Java services. I couldn't find anything like that for Node JS.

The other option is to just add the metrics to the logs and then use some sort of scraping to create metrics. The problem is with AWS there is some latency.